# Heroku Django foreman start error exited with code 1 mac

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

foreman start

```
01:25:49 web.1  | started with pid 3584
01:25:55 web.1  | exited with code 1
01:25:55 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn herokudjango.wsgi
```

requirements.txt

```
Django==1.6.5
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.5
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==19.0.0
psycopg2==2.5.3
pystache==0.5.4
static==1.0.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Hi, I simply follow https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django

It works fine after git push to heroku.

However, using foreman start doesn't return an ip for test running. I installed the heroku toolbelt from the download package and pip django-toolbelt from terminal. Anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

The answer:
http://thefreshlybaked.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/setting-up-django-on-heroku-with-postgresql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced the same issue. after installing gunicorn==0.16.1
using pip i resolved my problem... Hope this will resolve your problem too....

Answer (score 1):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#developing-locally-with-foreman

Take a look at the docs, by default foreman loads on port 5000. I believe you can change it to whatever port you want in the procfile.