# Foreman Start says "started with pid #" python

Tags: python, heroku, foreman

When I call 'foreman start' to run my database locally it says "started with pid ___" and then just stays there forever. I've looked at other solutions such as [foreman only shows line with “started wit pid #” and nothing else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717198/foreman-only-shows-line-with-started-wit-pid-and-nothing-else), and people said that the log was just buffering and I could wait, but it really does stay like that forever.

I have tried putting PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True in my environ file, but this did not fix the problem. I've double checked that I have the Heroku toolbelt and Foreman installed correctly.
I also attempted calling python -u script.py to avoid stdout buffering, but for some reason the log reads that it can't find 'script.py' in my Python directory. This makes me think that I have some dependencies installed incorrectly.

Can someone help me so that I can use foreman? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is with new gunicorn package, install gunicorn==0.16.1 in your virtualenv

[Heroku Django foreman start error exited with code 1 mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392907/heroku-django-foreman-start-error-exited-with-code-1-mac/24605786#24605786)